# Chat GPT & Flutter Integration

Tags: flutter, dart, openai-api, chatgpt-api

Hey guys hope you are doing great;

I am working on a new project which is integrating ChatGPT to a flutter app but I am getting 400 ERROR code.

I want to use chat gpt directly in the app and I don't understand what's wrong, I am not sure about the endpoints and the JSON body part :/

Here is my full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart'
    as http;

void
    main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class OpenAIGPTService {
  final String apiKey;
  final String endpoint;

  OpenAIGPTService(this.apiKey, this.endpoint);

  Future<String> generateResponse(String prompt) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(endpoint),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $apiKey',
      },
      body: jsonEncode({
        "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        'prompt': prompt,
        'max_tokens': 100, // Adjust as needed
      }),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return jsonDecode(response.body)['choices'][0]['text'];
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to generate response: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  }
}

class MyApp
    extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'ChatGPT Flutter App',
      home: ChatScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class ChatScreen
    extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => ChatScreenState();
}

class ChatScreenState
    extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final OpenAIGPTService gptService = OpenAIGPTService(
    'MY_API_KEY',
    'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions',
  );
  final TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();
  final List<String> _messages = [];

  void _handleSubmitted(String text) async {
    _textController.clear();
    setState(() {
      _messages.add('You: $text');
    });

    try {
      String response = await gptService.generateResponse(text);
      print(response);
      setState(() {
        _messages.add('ChatGPT: $response');
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _messages.add('Error: Failed to get ChatGPT response: $e');
      });
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('ChatGPT Flutter App'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _messages.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(_messages[index]),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Divider(height: 1.0),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).cardColor),
            child: _buildTextComposer(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTextComposer() {
    return IconTheme(
      data: IconThemeData(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary),
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: TextField(
                controller: _textController,
                onSubmitted: _handleSubmitted,
                decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: 'Send a message'),
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.send),
              onPressed: () => _handleSubmitted(_textController.text),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the [Devtools - Network View](https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/network) and see if there are other information from the error response?